# Images from Resources folder for custom controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to make a WPF window with a control realized by an array of RadioButtons, each of which is represented by a picture. I've used a template provided in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060859/wpf-radio-button-with-image), so the template looks like that:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="20">                                    
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Content, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now the problem is that, in order to set the picture on the control, I have to write the whole path to the picture, like that

```
<RadioButton Name="radioButtonNo" Checked="radioButton_Checked"
        Content="C:\Myfolder\MyProject\Resources\MyPic0.png" 
        Style="{StaticResource Flag}" Width="75"/>
```

Naturally, I'd wish to be able to write something like

```
<RadioButton Name="radioButtonNo" Checked="radioButton_Checked"
        Content="MyPic0.png" 
        Style="{StaticResource Flag}" Width="75"/>
```

but when I do this, all I get is a standard RadioButton with the filename as a caption. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be sufficient to provide a correct relative path, like

```
<RadioButton Content="Resources/MyPic0.png" .../>
```

Note that image resources in WPF are usually managed as assembly resource files. Their Build Action is set to `Resource` and they are referenced by [Resource File Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). The XAML parser automatically adds the missing `pack://application:,,,/` prefix.

---

You may as well explicitly create the ImageSource instance that is assigned to the Source property of the Image control in the ControlTemplate:

```
<RadioButton ...>
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="Resources/MyPic0.png"/>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Or with an explicitly written Pack URI:

```
<RadioButton ...>
    <RadioButton.Content>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/MyPic0.png"/>
    </RadioButton.Content>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Well, I did try 'Content="Resources/MyPic0.png"' as well as paths of different lengths, and manually adding the prefix. It didn't work in my case.

Trying to specify UriSource (in both ways proposed) led to a standard RadioButton with full path as a caption.

Comment: The image file must be in a folder named "Resources" in your Visual Studio project. Its Build Action must be Resource. You may of course use any other folder name or folder structure, e.g. "Images/MyPic0.jpg".

Comment: The file is there. Drag-and-dropped it into the Resources in the project on the first place. See in the resource folder in the solution explorer.

I mean, it looks so strange for me, because everything works perfectly fine, without even a need to write Resources, when I specify image for a control directly, without 'Content='. And yet fails for these custom RadioButtons.

Comment: You did not by accident forget to set `Style="{StaticResource Flag}"`?

Comment: I did, my bad. Thanks, now it finally seems to work.

Comment: Please note that you can also declare a *default* Style that is automatically applied to all RadioButtons. Just don't set an `x:Key` on the Style in the Resources.