# How to use images to store value instead of radio buttons?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I am creating a review system in c#.

Right now my program looks like this
[image]

I want to create smiley faces like this instead of those radio buttons
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF radio button with Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35060859/wpf-radio-button-with-image)

Comment: You could create an ImageList with 10 images and upon CheckedChanged set the ImageIndex to either 1..5 or 6..10 for the checked ones; if you set a Tag to an index 0..4 fro each RadioButton this can be achieved in a common event handler. Then place (Location and z-order) them in such a way that each covers the small button of its left neighbour and the leftmost such that its button is off the container; best place them in a Panel. Done. Best create a UserControl to hold all.

Comment: Hm, Instead of tweaking the placement this is simpler and more flexible: Change like so`Apperance.Button; FlatStyle.Flat, BorderSize= 0; BackColor=Color.White;`

Comment: And if your images are semi-transparent you can even get away with only 1 per button and simply change the `CheckedBackColor` from White to Yellow..