# WPF - How to set Bound property directly in the XAML file, with preset fixed values?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, data-binding, preset

I would like to know if it is possible to set a BOUND int variable/property in the XAML, giving it a fixed value written directly in the XAML file, in a control that behaves like a button:

click from btn1 set to 1, click from btn2 set to 2, ...

At the moment the only similar thing I use is a combobox with default values:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding TestInt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Content">

    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="0"/>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="3"/>

</ComboBox>
```

I tried with the "Command" of the Button object, but it seems very resource-intensive and complicated due to the CanExecute() task.

I'd like it to be manageable only in the XAML, so that I can BIND several controls to the same variable, each of which sets a different value, but I don't know which control to use for this purpose

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use heavily restyled ListBox and bind Selected item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793958/1506454

Comment: As a note, when you set `SelectedValuePath="Content"`, the binding should not be on the Text property, but instead `SelectedValue="{Binding TestInt}"`. Besides that, you could perhaps create a ListBox with ToggleButtons that have their IsChecked property bound to the IsSelected property of their ListBoxItem containers.

Comment: Binding a property of view element like Button and a property of view model is different thing from changing a property of view model when an event of view element occurs. Said that, if you want to change a property of view model when Button is clicked, ChangePropertyAction of XAML behavior of WPF could be useful.